# How do adjust discrete scale limits and intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my Y axis in the following graph to go from 0 to 100 at intervals of 10.

I have tried various ways of doing this this but (ylim, scale_y_continuous etc.) but keep getting error messages.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(janitor)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(forcats)

#Create data frame
df <- data.frame(Year = c("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"),
                         ExpeditedDrugsProportion = c(51, 48, 66, 60, 73, 61, 73, 60, 68, 74, 65)
)

df$ExpeditedDrugsProportion <- as.factor(df$ExpeditedDrugsProportion)

#Create plot, labels etc.
ExpeditedApprovals_graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = ExpeditedDrugsProportion)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Proportion of newly approved drugs expedited (%)") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) 

  
ExpeditedApprovals_graph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not turn your x-axis variable into a factor and it works with `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(janitor)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(forcats)

#Create data frame
df <- data.frame(Year = c("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"),
                 ExpeditedDrugsProportion = c(51, 48, 66, 60, 73, 61, 73, 60, 68, 74, 65)
)

#Create plot, labels etc.
ExpeditedApprovals_graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = ExpeditedDrugsProportion)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Proportion of newly approved drugs expedited (%)") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))


ExpeditedApprovals_graph
```